# Wicket: make a generated csv available to a dygraphs JavaScript

Tags: java, javascript, wicket

I'm trying to figure out how to make a dynamically generated csv available to a dygraphs JavaScript.

I'm using a wicket behavior to add the dygraph (JavaScript graph) to my markup like shown in the codesample bellow. Right now I've hardcoded it to use a csv file named "dygraph.csv". I want to change this, and instead make dygraph use the values from String csv, how do I achieve this?

Any help help is greatly appreciated.

```
public class DygraphBehavior extends AbstractBehavior {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = -516501274090062937L;
    private static final CompressedResourceReference DYGRAPH_JS = new CompressedResourceReference(DygraphBehavior.class, "dygraph-combined.js");

    @Override
    public void renderHead(IHeaderResponse response) {
        response.renderJavascriptReference(DYGRAPH_JS);
    }
    @Override
    public void onRendered(Component component) {
        final String id = component.getId();
        Response response = component.getResponse();

        response.write(JavascriptUtils.SCRIPT_OPEN_TAG);
        response.write("new Dygraph(document.getElementById(\""+id+"\"), \"dygraph.csv\", {rollPeriod: 7, showRoller: true, errorBars: true});");
        response.write(JavascriptUtils.SCRIPT_CLOSE_TAG);
    }
}
```

---

```
public class Dygraph extends WebPage {
    public Dygraph() {
        String csv = "Date,ms\n20070101,62\n20070102,62";
        add(new ResourceLink<File>("csv", new ByteArrayResource("text/csv", csv.getBytes())));

        add(new Label("graphdiv").add(new DygraphBehavior()));
    }
}
```

---

```
<div>
    <h1>Dygraph:</h1>
    <div wicket:id="graphdiv" id="graphdiv" style="width:500px; height:300px;"></div>
    <a wicket:id="csv" href="#">dl generated csv</a>
</div>
```

Comment: Hmm, you've already found the way as far as I can see: create a resource. What is the part that isn't working?

Comment: ResourceLink creates a clickable link to the resource, I'm trying to find a way to get only the url to the resource, that's where I'm stuck.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
public class Dygraph extends WebPage {
    public Dygraph() {
        String csv = "Date,ms\n20070101,62\n20070102,62";
        ResourceLink<File> link = new ResourceLink<File>("csv", new ByteArrayResource("text/csv", csv.getBytes()));
        add( link );

        //this is the url that should be passed to the javascript code
        CharSequence url = link.urlFor( IResourceListener.INTERFACE ); 

        add(new Label("graphdiv").add(new DygraphBehavior()));
    }
}
```

There are other solutions based on the scope of your resource, maybe a dynamic shared resource would work better (if your graph parameters can simply be passed as url parameters), but this will work.

Answer (score 0):

The JavaScript needs to see the data in some way *after* the page has been rendered. So you have two options:

1. Embed the data in the page (say in a hidden `div`) and then let JavaScript read the data from there as text.
2. Create a servlet where the JavaScript can download the data from.

The second option means that your page rendering code has to pass the data somehow to the servlet. You can try to put it into the session but then, it will sit there, occupying RAM. Probably not a problem if it's just a little bit of data and you have only a few users. But if that's not true, option #1 is probably better.

Comment: There are mechanisms in Wicket to deal with resources, creating a separate servlet to serve a resource would be overkill.